# Use dc-leaflet in an Angular 4 app

Tags: angular, leaflet, dc.js

I need to use dc and dc-leaflet in an Angular 4 app.
There is an angular-dc package for AngularJS, but it seems there is no such package for Angular 2/4. So I installed dc (and crossfilter) and then I include it in my components with:

```
let dc = require('dc');
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this... But it works...

Now, I need to use dc-leaflet. I installed dc-addons and I tried to import leaflet like this:

```
let dc = require('dc');
let leaflet = require('dc-addons/dist/leaflet-map/dc-leaflet');
```

But I got the error "ReferenceError: dc is not defined at dc-leaflet.js:10"

So, I don't know how to use a non-angular-package that depends on another. Perhaps I could import dc as a global package, I didn't try this but I am not sure that it would be the proper way.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: If you were able to solve this problem then could you please share how you did it? I am facing the same problem as well.

Comment: No sorry, I did'nt solve the problem...